# How to replace sql field case-sensitive value

Tags: sql, replace, case-sensitive

I have one case-sensitive column.
How can I replace  (Shpersonel,shPersonel, sHperSonel) to ShPersonel in all records?

my column Data is:

```
1- SHpersonel = 12 And Password= Ayuy122
2- ShpeRsonel = 10 And Password= jkjIUD122
3- ShPersonel = 08 And Password= Kjjam
...
```

Comment: What kind of database do you use? See also this [UPPER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/upper-transact-sql) function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LOWER` (or `UPPER`), which lots of DBMSes support, to look for a value case insensitively and update:

```
update your_table
set col = 'ShPersonel'
where lower(col) = 'shpersonel';
```

#### EDIT:

Further clarification explained that above data is stored in a single column - Which is not how it should be stored.

You should store the data in separate columns and then look for further normalization to remove unwanted dependencies.

Comment: but this solution can delete all 'Password'! . i want just replace shpersonel

Comment: @SNasrZ - Wait a minute ... Is the data you gave in question stored in one single column? exactly as you showed? If so, you need to fix your table structure. Normalize it. This is not the way to store data.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_table
   SET your_column = 'ShPersonel'
 WHERE upper(your_column) = 'SHPERSONEL';
```

Comment: but this solution can delete all 'Password'! . i want just replace "shpersonel"

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what DBMS you're using. If it's SQL-Server, the following should work for you:

```
update MyTable
set TheData =
    concat(
           left(TheData,charindex('shpersonel',lower(t.TheData))-1),
           'ShPersonel',
           right(t.TheData,len(t.TheData) - charindex('shpersonel',lower(t.TheData)) - len('ShPersonel'))
           )           
from MyTable t
where
charindex('shpersonel',lower(t.TheData))>0
```

For other DBMS's you need to replace charindex with whatever that DBMS's equivalent may be. For example, Oracle and MySQL use `InStr` (which needs its arguments in the reverse order).